# Running turtlebot simulator in willow garage world

Tags: gazebo, simulation, turtlebot, turtlebot-simulator, gazebo-worlds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im trying to run my turtlebot simulator in the willow garage world in gazebo and im wondering the best way of going about it, if anyone has any idea i would be grateful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12956/running-turtlebot-simulator-in-willow-garage-world/) by [Patrick](https://answers.ros.org/users/1729/patrick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2012-02-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use this launch file:

```
 <launch>
   <!-- start gazebo with an empty plane -->
   <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />
 
   <node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo" type="gazebo" args="$(find gazebo_worlds)/worlds/wg.world" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
 
 
   <include file="$(find turtlebot_gazebo)/launch/robot.launch"/>
 </launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ali ekber celik](https://answers.ros.org/users/8866/ali-ekber-celik/) on 2013-11-16**:
Hi,how can i do this with ros hydro?I have tried your solution but it did not work for me.i use ros hydro and gazebo 1.9.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note that the solution above doesn't work for ROS Indigo and above. I got this to work:

```
<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/willowgarage_world.launch">
```

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2017-10-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2